# Find Consecutive Records with Timestamp Interval > 15 mins

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp, sql-server-2012, intervals

A process runs (is supposed to run) every 15 mins and add and entry to a MS SQL 2012 logging table.

```
2013-02-07 10:07:47.000
2013-02-07 09:52:36.000
2013-02-07 09:37:34.000
2013-02-07 09:22:32.000
2013-02-07 09:07:31.000
2013-02-07 08:52:29.000
2013-02-07 08:37:28.000
2013-02-07 08:13:53.000
2013-02-07 07:58:51.000
2013-02-07 07:43:50.000
2013-02-07 07:28:48.000
2013-02-07 07:13:47.000
2013-02-07 06:58:37.000
```

I need help with a query that will return consecutive timestamps that are > 16 minutes apart.  In the above records, the query would return 2013-02-07 08:37:28.000 and 2013-02-07 08:13:53.000

EDIT - Add reference to MS SQL

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question very much depends one which RDBMS you are using.

Something like this should work for SQL Server using `DATEDIFF` and `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ProcessTime, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProcessTime DESC) RN
  FROM Process
  )
SELECT P.ProcessTime, 
  P2.ProcessTime as ProcessTime2, 
  DATEDIFF(mi,  P.ProcessTime, P2.ProcessTime)
FROM CTE P
  JOIN CTE P2 ON P.RN = P2.RN + 1
WHERE DATEDIFF(mi, P.ProcessTime, P2.ProcessTime) > 16
```

It's putting the dates in 2 separate columns -- easy enough to put in a single column if preferred.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2aa3/5).

If you let us know the RDBMS, we could put together an alternative solution if needed.

For Oracle, use `extract( minute from P2.ProcessTime - P.ProcessTime )` vs `DATEDIFF` - the rest of the query should work -- here is the [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/537ab/5).

For MySQL, the code would be a little different as MySQL doesn't support `CTEs` or `ROW_NUMBER`.  But this should get you in the right direction.

Good luck.

Comment: sgeddes, thank you for the prompt reply.  This is running on MS SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @paparush -- Gotcha, then the above should work for you.  Best of luck!

Comment: @paparush -- No problem, glad we could help!

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to put in the next time stamp in the series and then select the rows where the difference is greater than 16.

The following query calculates the next time stamp using a correlated subquery:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             (select MIN(t.timestamp) from t t2 where t2.timestamp > t.timestamp
             ) as nextTimestamp
      from t
     ) t
where DATEDIFF(min, timestamp, nextTimestamp) > 16
```

The `where` clause is database-dependent, but it gives an idea of how to do this.

On SQL Server 2012, you would do:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             lead (t.timestamp) over (order by timestamp) as nextTimestamp
      from t
     ) t
where DATEDIFF(mi, timestamp, nextTimestamp) > 16
```

(assuming that your timestamps are stored as `datetime`).

Comment: Gordon, thank you for the reply.  This is running on MS SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @paparush - why use joins if you have lead()/lag() in 2012 server.